# Preventing Google Drive document viewer from caching PDF

Tags: caching, pdf, google-drive-api

I've implemented a feature which will enable users to "highlight" text in a PDF file stored on Google Drive and then automatically update the file on Drive.

However, when the file is viewed on the web a cached image is displayed of the page and does not reflect the highlighted text.  If I download the file or manually change the image size the highlighted text is displayed.

Is there any undocumented URL parameter that I can add to the Drive files Edit/View URL that will prevent the use of cached images?  Or some other method that may have worked for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around this issue by developing a simple Chrome Extension that will automatically add cache expiry headers for the images, fortunately our application is only used internally so forcing the installation of a Chrome Extension is not an issue.

Not the best solution, however it works.

Answer (score 0):

There are no parameters to disable caching, the previews and the rendered images are invalidated on content modifications. It could be a Drive issue if you're still seeing the invalidated images.

Comment: It is correct that the previews will update when the content is modified, however if you have already previewed the PDF the image is cached by the browser, so you do not get an updated image unless you change the image size (i.e. zoom in or out).  The easiest fix I can think of would be that the preview image URL is suffixed with the last modified timestamp (or something of the sort which would change on a file change) e.g. https://docs.google.com/a/domain.com/file/d/fileId/image?pagenumber=1&w=800&m=1234567890 testing this manually works as the preview reflects the changes

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried appending an arbitrary query string to the url, eg. https://googlecontent.g.com/blahblah?timestamp

Comment: Yes, I noted that in my comment above, by appending a unique string to the URL of the image the correct image is displayed, however the issue is that that the viewer is loaded from a different URL and then the viewer is the one that is rendering the pdf pages (as images) these URLs you have no control over.  If Google just appended the last modified date to the image URL everything would be OK.  I'm currently working on a Chrome Extension which will automatically append a unique parameter to the URL, this works, however not for my use case because I'm using GWT with dynamic iFrames.

Comment: I think I've misunderstood the question. Are you saying it's the browser caching the old version, or the Google Drive webapp that has cached the old version?

Comment: Its the browser caching the image of the document, in this case a PDF.  This is because the image URL is not modified when there is a change to the document, nor are any cache expiry headers set for the image.  So if you view a PDF, edit the PDF and then view the PDF again, the image will be pulled from cache.